# Getting 0 value in tinyMCE 4 when tinyMCE.activeEditor.queryCommandValue("FontSize"); is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I need to get the current value of the FontSize of the tinyMCE WYSWYG editor.
The problem is when the text on the textarea is not selected and the TextSize button is clicked, it is giving me  the correct value that is selected, by using this

```js
editor.on('ExecCommand', function(editor) {

  var val = tinyMCE.activeEditor.queryCommandValue("FontSize");
  alert(val)

});
```

But when I select some text in the text area and FontSize is selected, It is giving me 0 value in the alert.
What I need to do to get the current selected value in any case. Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you build a small simplified fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I think it should be changed to `editor.queryCommandValue("FontSize");`

Comment: @Julo0sS - Here is the working example I am trying. https://jsfiddle.net/rachits21/d3h060np/5/   . Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - I got it solved by replacing **"editor.value"** instead of val. It fetches the current *execCommand* Value in any case.